# Repeating Text to Speech while certain event is happening

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am working on android app and I am making use of the TTS engine. The app should output a message with continuous repetition for the duration of a certain event.

I've currently being doing it in a `while(true)` statement adding to the queue, but then thought that this probably isn't a good idea as I don't think the TTS.speak method is blocking so it will continuously add speech to the tts engine that probably won't get used or could cause problems such as memory issues or performance issues.

Is there a way to make the program the wait for the text to speech to finish, and once complete it can loop through and replay the message again and so on. Is this possible or is there a better solution for what I have done.

Below is the code that I have so far

```
if (repitionOption.equals(SettingsManager.CALL_ANNOUNCE_CONTINUOUSLY))
{
    while (true)
    {
    textToSpeech.speak(ttsMessage, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Hey I also used looping but it is bad for phone resources, so I decided to use onUteranceCompleted(). The problem is I am calling tts.speak() in an screen event handler, so as long the user has pressed the screen, I want to speak some text but the uterance method seems not to be working. I am also puting KEY_PARAM_STREAM in hashmap along with KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID. I am using KEY_PARAM_STREAM  for some other reason. What can I do?

Comment: I think you're going to have to post your own question. Its impossible to be able to provide help without seeing some code for how you have implemented it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement **onUtteranceCompleted** and call speak there again if your condition is true.